# Why can't I use a reference to a `Bump` after a call to `reset`?

Tags: rust, compiler-errors

I'm currently testing out arenas. I actually expected this code to compile but fail at runtime, so pleasantly surprised the compiler caught the issue. But I don't know if it's reasoning is correct. Can someone explain it to me?

```rust
use bumpalo::Bump;

fn main() {
    let mut bump = Bump::new();
    let b1: &mut Bob = bump.alloc(Bob::default());
    let b2: &mut Bob = bump.alloc(Bob::default());
    let b3: &mut Bob = bump.alloc(Bob::new(Some(b1), Some(b2)));
    println!("{:?}", b2);
    {
        bump.reset();
    }
    println!("{:?}", b2);
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Bob {
    son: Option<*mut Bob>,
    parent: Option<*mut Bob>,
    string: String,
}
impl Bob {
    fn new(son: Option<*mut Bob>, parent: Option<*mut Bob>) -> Bob {
        Bob {
            son,
            parent,
            ..Bob::default()
        }
    }
}

impl Default for Bob {
    fn default() -> Bob {
        Bob {
            son: None,
            parent: None,
            string: String::from("Hello"),
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `bump` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src\main.rs:10:9
   |
6  |     let b2: &mut Bob = bump.alloc(Bob::default());
   |                        -------------------------- immutable borrow occurs here
...
10 |         bump.reset();
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
11 |     }
12 |     println!("{:?}", b2);
   |                      -- immutable borrow later used here
```

Relevant code from bumpalo:

```rust
pub fn alloc<T>(&self, val: T) -> &mut T {
    self.alloc_with(|| val)
}
```

```rust
#[inline(always)]
#[allow(clippy::mut_from_ref)]
pub fn alloc_with<F, T>(&self, f: F) -> &mut T
where
    F: FnOnce() -> T,
{
    #[inline(always)]
    unsafe fn inner_writer<T, F>(ptr: *mut T, f: F)
    where
        F: FnOnce() -> T,
    {
        // This function is translated as:
        // - allocate space for a T on the stack
        // - call f() with the return value being put onto this stack space
        // - memcpy from the stack to the heap
        //
        // Ideally we want LLVM to always realize that doing a stack
        // allocation is unnecessary and optimize the code so it writes
        // directly into the heap instead. It seems we get it to realize
        // this most consistently if we put this critical line into it's
        // own function instead of inlining it into the surrounding code.
        ptr::write(ptr, f())
    }

    let layout = Layout::new::<T>();

    unsafe {
        let p = self.alloc_layout(layout);
        let p = p.as_ptr() as *mut T;
        inner_writer(p, f);
        &mut *p
    }
}
```

```rust
pub fn reset(&mut self) {
    // Takes `&mut self` so `self` must be unique and there can't be any
    // borrows active that would get invalidated by resetting.
    unsafe {
        if self.current_chunk_footer.get().as_ref().is_empty() {
            return;
        }

        let mut cur_chunk = self.current_chunk_footer.get();

        // Deallocate all chunks except the current one
        let prev_chunk = cur_chunk.as_ref().prev.replace(EMPTY_CHUNK.get());
        dealloc_chunk_list(prev_chunk);

        // Reset the bump finger to the end of the chunk.
        cur_chunk.as_ref().ptr.set(cur_chunk.cast());

        // Reset the allocated size of the chunk.
        cur_chunk.as_mut().allocated_bytes = cur_chunk.as_ref().layout.size();

        debug_assert!(
            self.current_chunk_footer
                .get()
                .as_ref()
                .prev
                .get()
                .as_ref()
                .is_empty(),
            "We should only have a single chunk"
        );
        debug_assert_eq!(
            self.current_chunk_footer.get().as_ref().ptr.get(),
            self.current_chunk_footer.get().cast(),
            "Our chunk's bump finger should be reset to the start of its allocation"
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Uh, this is pretty basic. All immutable references to `bump`, like `b1`, `b2`, and `b3` must end their lifetimes before you take a mutable reference to `bump` to call `reset`. Exactly so that you don't dereference `b3` after deallocating it.

Answer (score 3):

The signature for `Bump.alloc` is:

```
pub fn alloc<T>(&self, val: T) -> &mut T
```

This signature is exploiting [Lifetime Elision](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/lifetime-elision.html) rules to avoid including explicit lifetime information. The relevant rule is:

> If there are multiple input lifetime positions, but one of them is `&self` or `&mut self`, the lifetime of self is assigned to all elided output lifetimes.

All references in a signature must have *some* lifetime, so the compiler infers some for this function. Based on the above rule, the signature is effectively:

```
pub fn alloc<T>(&'a self, val: T) -> &'a mut T
```

...or in other words, the result of this function must not outlive the `Bump` that `self` refers to, which is hopefully intuitive because the `Bump` owns the memory that the allocation belongs to.

The `Bump.reset` function has this signature:

```
pub fn reset(&mut self)
```

This method takes a `mut` (exclusive) reference to `self`, which means it cannot be called while any other reference to the same object is "live". "Live" here means that later code might make use of it.

Your code tries to use `b2` after calling `reset`, which means that the `b2` reference remains live across the call to `reset`. `b2` has the same lifetime as this `&mut self`, so that is illegal. The reference `b2` is effectively a reference to the `Bump` object (a part of the memory that belongs to it), and so it shares the same lifetime as described above.

If you remove that final reference to `b2` after `reset` then this code should compile, because then none of the references to parts of `bump` will still be live at the time of `reset`.